# pagination and sorting on 'ngOnInit' is not working after placing my constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a mat-table using pagination and sorting, it works properly until I place my constructor: `"constructor(private _router: Router){}"`. The table is still showing, but pagination and sorting doesn't. It shows everything all at once. I am new to angular and I'm having trouble identifying the problem.

I tried placing the contents on 'ngOnInit' on the constructor, and in still didn't seem to work.

```
export class LogsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router: Router){} //If i place this, it works but pagination doesn't

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(EXAMPLE_DATA);
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'role', 'date'];

  applyFilter(filterValue: string, _router: Router) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
//The one I use on mg 'logs' page
<div *ngIf="_router.url == '/logs'">
   <div class="table">
      //table here
   </div>
</div>

//The on I use on the dashboard
<div *ngIf="_router.url != '/logs'">
   <div class="table">
      //table here
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to know why is this not working, I've read from some pages that the constructor gets read first before the `ngOnInit()`. But its not working in my case, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: can u try `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` and lemme know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"can u try [hidden] instead of *ngIf and lemme know if it works – Vikas May 30 at 6:42"

Answer By @Vikas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error in the console?
If you didn't import the router module you will see a StaticInjectorError.
To fix this error add the following to your app.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML content to your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I noticed that you have the _router variable private and you are trying to access from your view, the other thing that I noticed is your applyFilter function, I don't understand  why you are expecting a router parameter if you have it clearly in your class scope. But, back to your problem is your private router variable, try to change it to public.

When something in angular goes wrong, the next steps result interrupted and it's for that reason that your paginator and sort functions have interrupted.

You have to import the RouterModule in your AppModule previously.

Comment: I tried changing it to 'public' but it didn't work :( and another thing is that it was my mistake to place the 'Router' in the 'applyFilter' and I have already removed it.